# JPQL and clausole IN, not found

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, jpql

i have the following situation:

In the dao class:

```
...
Query q = em.createNamedQuery("myQuery");
q.setParameter("attr", "value");
List<MyObj> listMyObj = q.getResultList();
...
```

In my file orm.xlm, i defined this query:

```
<named-query name="myQuery">
    <query><![CDATA[
      select m from MyEntity1 
         where id_est in (select mm.id from MyEntity2 where mm.id_est = :attr)
    ]]></query>
</named-query>
```

Everything works, there are no configuration problems and / or code, but this query returns 0 elements, when execute the same query in sql returns items expected . Why? There is something i ignore in JPQL?

Comment: Try turning the logging on and see what is the exact SQL it generates.

Comment: I have enabled the property "hibernate.show_sql", the generated query is correct and i try execute in SqlDeveloper, it's works. For me is a problem of cache

Comment: Another detail: i use spring-orm module for inject the persistence-unit

Comment: In any case, as I do to force him to retrieve the object from the db but not the cache??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, if mm.id_est is a String when you set parameter don't use

```
" 'value' "
```

but use

```
" value "
```

...this was my problem. Fortunately, thanks to this post I realized that in my code I had written as I wrote here on StackOverflow